# Any Tips for Writing a Google Gadget / Google Android App?

Tags: android, google-gadget

I'm going to be starting on a project building a Google Gadget and a Google Android with similar functionality.

I've read through a bit of  the documentation, but before I start I thought I'd ask if anyone has any tips they'd like to share to make the job easier.

I program in lots of different languages, so I don't think it'll be too hard, but are there any traps for the unwary ?

Answer (score 0):

What is a "Google Android"?  I assume you mean an Android application to run on the Android operating system.  The first thing I suggest is that you should read through the documentation enough to get a basic understanding of the platform.

There are already plenty of questions on here asking the same thing you have.  Just take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934161/android-app-development/) question for a good starting point.